# Zend PHP Script running incredibly slowly

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have the following code

```
$Model_Shifts = new Model_Shifts();
$shifts = $Model_Shifts->getShiftIDs($condition->schedule_id);
$Model_Tasks = new Model_Tasks();
$tasks = $Model_Tasks->getTasksByShiftIDsPositionID($shifts, $condition->position_id, $time);
return count($tasks);
```

My `Model_Shifts->getShiftIDs()` is the following

```
public function getShiftIDs($schedule_id)
{
    $row = $this->fetchAll(
                $this->select()
                     ->from($this->_name, 'id' )
                     ->where('schedule_id = ?', $schedule_id)
        );
    return $row->toArray();
}
```

And my `$Model_Tasks->getTasksByShiftIDsPositionID` is the following

```
public function getTasksByShiftIDsPositionID( $shift_ids, $position_id, $time)
{
    return $this->fetchAll($this->select()
                                ->where('shift_id IN (?)', $shift_ids)
                                ->where('position_id = ?', $position_id)
                                ->where('time_start <= ?', $time)
                                ->where('time_end > ?', $time)
                                );
}
```

This runs extremely slow! It takes about 5 seconds to load. My database is not large at all. What operation am I running that is causing this to be so slow?

I know it is this code that is causing the server to run slow. I commented the code out, and the code then runs in under 10ms.

EDIT:
- time_start and time_end are (int 4) in my database. 
- I used microtime to calculate how long each function is taking. Roughly speaking, each of those two functions takes half the time (so 2.5seconds).

Comment: Good to see someone using a PDO. I think you will find it will be your database selects. What type of columns are time_start and time_end? Are these integers or datetimes? And are they indexed? Its also worthwhile indexing your foreign keys. My advice would be to find out how long each function takes to execute using microtime(); and if it is your SQL, there are plenty of steps you can take to optimize it.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. time_start and time_end are (int 4). And each function takes about 2.5second to run

Comment: The answer provided by Nandakumar V will help speed up the query, but it depends on the amount of records its counting as to how much it will help. Also consider running a single query to accomplish the entire task, rather than getting an array of the shift ID then doing a second query using each of those items in the array.

Comment: Do you have indexes on these tables? If so, what are they? Rougly how many rows do each function return/examine?

Comment: combine the query insert the first query as subquery for the second one: `->where('shift_id IN (?)', $subQuery)` i dont know how many ids there are but this would atleast increase the performance a little

Comment: The description and tags make no mention of the database - you've not done any investigation to determine if the slowness is in the database or in PHP (it's nearly always the database which is slower - but regardless you can't fix the problem without isolating it first).

Comment: Putting a subquery into `IN ()` slows everything even more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need only the count of tasks from the `getTasksByShiftIDsPositionID` function update your query to return only the count.
It is faster than fetching all rows and then taking the count

```
public function getShiftIDs($schedule_id)
{
    $row = $this->fetchAll(
                $this->select()
                     ->from($this->_name, 'id' )
                     ->where('schedule_id = ?', $schedule_id)
        );
    return $row->__toString();
}
```

---

```
public function getTasksByShiftIDsPositionID( $shift_ids, $position_id, $time)
{
    $select = $this->select()
                    ->from($this->_name, array('COUNT(shift_id) AS shiftcount'))
                    ->where('shift_id IN (?)', $shift_ids)
                    ->where('position_id = ?', $position_id)
                    ->where('time_start <= ?', $time)
                    ->where('time_end > ?', $time);

    $result = $this->fetchRow($select)
    return $result->shiftcount;
}
```

Or you can use join condition to connect the two tables and use the where condition to filter the result

```
$Model_Shifts = new Model_Shifts();
$shiftCount = $Model_Shifts->getShiftCount($condition->schedule_id,$condition->position_id, $time);

public function getShiftCount($schedule_id,$position_id, $time)
{
    $select = $this->select()
                    ->from($this->_name, array('COUNT(shift_id) AS shiftcount'))
                    ->join(array('task'=>'shift_task'),$this->_name.'.id=task.shift_id', array())
                    ->where('position_id = ?', $position_id)
                    ->where('time_start <= ?', $time)
                    ->where('time_end > ?', $time)
                    ->where('schedule_id = ?', $schedule_id)
    $result = $this->fetchRow($select)
    return $result->shiftcount;
}
```

Comment: That only reduced the computation time by 0.3sec!

Comment: i have updated the answer.. hope that will reduce the execution time

Answer (score 0):

combine queries and use count in query instead of php increases speed.

```
function getAmountOfTasks($schedule_id){
  $stmtA =   $this->select()
                     ->from($this->_name, 'id' )
                     ->where('schedule_id = ?', $schedule_id);
  $data = $this->fetchRow($this->select()
                                ->from($this->_name, 'COUNT(*)' ) //probably need to change $this->_name here
                                ->where('shift_id IN (?)', $stmtA)
                                ->where('position_id = ?', $position_id)
                                ->where('time_start <= ?', $time)
                                ->where('time_end > ?', $time)
                                );
  return $data[0];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I`m agreeing with the people who say to combine your queries. "shift_id IN (?)" is very slow and probably that is the issue you have. 
Also adding indexes to your fields that you use often in your "Where" clauses will increase speed a lot.